# No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.UUID' available in SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, javabeans, autowired, applicationcontext

I'm using SpringBoot for application creation.

On of components in app-packages is:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ContentDTO {
    private UUID uuid;
    private ContentAction contentAction;
    private String payload;
}
```

In test-package I create utils-class for creating tets-data:

```
 @Component
 public class TestData {

     private UUID uuid = null;
     private final ContentAction contentAction = ContentAction.valueOf("SEND_NEW");
     private final String payload = "New message";
     private ContentDTO contentDTO;

     public TestData() {
       contentDTO = 
   ContentDTO.builder().uuid(uuid).contentAction(contentAction).payload(payload).build();     
  }

    public ContentDTO getContentDTO() {
        return contentDTO;
     }
 }
```

And test-class:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest(classes = {InfoDiodeSinkApplication.class, ContentDTO.class, TestData.class})
 public class InfoDiodeSinkApplicationTest {

 @Autowired
 private InfoDiodeSinkApplication infoDiodeSinkApplication;
 @Autowired
 private ContentDTO contentDTO;
 @Autowired
 private TestData testData;

 public void contextLoads() {
 }

 @Test(expected = Exception.class)
 public void testDtoHandler() {
     contentDTO = testData.getContentDTO();
     Mockito.doThrow(new 
       EOFException()).when(infoDiodeSinkApplication).dtoHandler(contentDTO);
   }
 }
```

But when I run the test, I receive:

```
   Error creating bean with name 'contentDTO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0
```

Caused by:

```
   No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.UUID' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

But java.util.UUID  included in standart java-lib. And I suppose that SpringBoot able to create default configuration for all beans from standart libs.

Do I understand correctly, that Spring suggest me to create a custom bean-configuration for standart UUID? And what am I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in using of lombock-@Builder. I changed lombock-builder on custom builder, and problem is gone

```
 @Getter
 @Component
 public class ContentDTO {

  private ContentDTO() {
      // private constructor
   }

   private UUID uuid;
   private ContentAction contentAction;
   private String payload;

   public static Builder newBuilder() {
       return new ContentDTO().new Builder();
  }

  public class Builder{
      private Builder() {
          // private constructor
      }

    public Builder uuid(UUID uuid) {
        ContentDTO.this.uuid = uuid;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder contentAction(ContentAction contentAction) {
        ContentDTO.this.contentAction = contentAction;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder payload(String payload) {
        ContentDTO.this.payload = payload;
        return this;
    }

    public ContentDTO build() {
        return ContentDTO.this;
      }
    
    }

 }
```